# This object is empty inside callback function of run() method

Tags: node.js, express, node-sqlite3

I'm writing a server using NodeJS, Express and SQLite in order to provice RESTful services.

I want to create an endpoint for adding a new user to the database. The endpoint receives a POST request with the parameters *username* and *password*, and responds with the *id* of the newly created user.

According to the `node-sqlite3` package [documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback), when the `run` method succeeds, the `this` object inside the callback function contains the properties `lastID` and `changes`.

My problem is that, even though the `run` method succeeds and the new user is `successfully` inserted into the database, the `this` object is empty.

What am I doing wrong? How can I access `this.lastID`?

```
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    const {
        username,
        password
    } = req.body;

    db.get(
        `SELECT id
        FROM Users
        WHERE username = ?`,
        [username],
        (err, row) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.sendStatus(500);
            } else if (row) {
                return res.status(400).send('Username already exist.');
            }

            db.run(
                `INSERT INTO Users (username, password)
                VALUES (?, ?)`,
                [username, password],
                (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        return res.sendStatus(500);
                    }
                    console.log(this); // prints {} to the console
                    res.send(this.lastID); // response body is empty
                }
            );
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an old-school `function` instead of an arrow function for your callback. I think with arrow functions `this` cannot be bound to a value.